# how do i tell heroku what version of php i am using?

Tags: php, heroku

I attempted to follow the help pages will no luck. 
this message appears to default to a version of php of its choosing then chastises me for picking an out of date version.

I am using php version 7.0.29 on my local server.
I ran composer update but it did not create a lock file as the help pages suggested

How do i get rid of this message?

[image: Console]

Comment: There is still an open discussion about if Heroku questions are on topic here. Regardless of whether they are or not, you should always include error messages as text rather than images. It greatly improves accessibility and search.

Comment: What do you have in your `composer.json`?  Can you add the relevant part to the question?

Comment: {}               that's it, the documentation says I don't even have to have anything but it errors if i don't have the brackets

Comment: this tools strips all white space. to the about is supposed to show just the contents as two brackets then newline but this text box script strips it out

Comment: Adrian Larson - Heroku sends you to this forum as the only support available for free users. personally i find heroku overly complicated and poorly documented but I am required to use it for a school assignment

Comment: I am actually using php 7.2.4 now

Comment: `{} that's it` --> Can you try specifying a version in your composer.json file?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with our PHP team. You're running on an older Heroku stack (not heroku-18). These older stacks will default to PHP 5, unless you specify a version in composer. So if you were to upgrade to heroku-18, the default would be PHP 7.2 Either way, it's highly recommended that you specify a version in your composer file.

Comment: How do I specify to PHP version in my composer file while I slumming it on the older stack?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#selecting-a-runtime

Comment: so I updated my composer to:

Comment: {
  "require": {
    "php": "~7.2.0"
  }
}
ran composer update but it complained I was running 5.6.35 but phpinfo() shows I am running 7.2.4. That failed so no I can't push because I have no composer lock file

Comment: apparently my heroku install has an old version of php. my WAMP environment where i develop has 7.2.4. how do I upgrade the php version that heroku is looking at?

Comment: I hit the upgrade button on the dashboard for my app and changed my composer to require ~7.2.0 This of course does not help and puts me in narrower box. My push fails because heroku thinks my app runs on 5.6.35 which it does not. That is information that Heroku is getting from somewhere other than my composer.json file. My development environment run 7.2.4 as verified by phpinfo(). Now I can't downgrade from heroku-18